# loading="lazy" does not work on images with a height or width and an aspect-ratio set in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, lazy-loading

I was wondering why my images were instantly loading after I visited my page, even though the attribute `loading` was set to `lazy` and they were not in view. More strangely, my site worked completely fine in Chrome.

After some stumbling around, I found out that Firefox needs a `width` **and** `height` assigned to an image to "make it lazy-load". It is unable to "lazy-load" an image with a `width` **or either** `height` value set combined with an `aspect-ratio`.

The snippet below works fine in Chrome, however, Firefox directly loads all assets on page load.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/european-short-haired-cat-picture-id1072769156?k=20&m=1072769156&s=612x612&w=0&h=k6eFXtE7bpEmR2ns5p3qe_KYh098CVLMz4iKm5OuO6Y=" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/feline-picture-id108226626?k=20&m=108226626&s=612x612&w=0&h=bDaWwxhcygjerdR71qQu8YFSXaDUIi_HUZV2AADg5L8=" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcOqTIP5d-oh7rSiqm_OK_Zc7ftCkmUvRtpZUt5yu6fyfO0_obEZO49r2_WQhkqBHGnpo&usqp=CAU" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/09/14/science/07CAT-STRIPES/07CAT-STRIPES-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://www.thesprucepets.com/thmb/QDw4vt7XXQejL2IRztKeRLow6hA=/2776x1561/smart/filters:no_upscale()/cat-talk-eyes-553942-hero-df606397b6ff47b19f3ab98589c3e2ce.jpg" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615789591457-74a63395c990?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8a2l0dHl8ZW58MHx8MHx8&w=1000&q=80" />
<img alt="Image of cat" loading="lazy" src="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/full/chicken_249474721.jpg" />
```

If you remove the `aspect-ratio: 1;` line and instead directly define a height e.g. `height: 100%;`, also Firefox does lazy-load the images.

I've found [this report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1621333) on Bugzilla, however it was closed, doesn't that mean it was fixed?
Is this intentional, if yes, why?